# IIS 10 trailing slash on Application

Tags: laravel, redirect, iis

I have currently got a view sites in sub folders of a site that have been converted to applications.

`example.com/folder`

When a user types a link with a slash at the end:

`example.com/folder/foobar/`

Then the redirect goes to the wrong place.

`example.com/foobar` instead of `example.com/folder/foobar`

I am using a Laravel and IIS 10 on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012.

From the RouteServiceProvider:

```
Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace . '\Admin')
        ->prefix('admin')
        ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
```

In the routes:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    die('here');
});
```

If `example.com/folder/admin` is hit then the text 'here' appears, if there is a slash at the end. Then you get redirected to `example.com/admin`.

Comment: post the defined route

Comment: @SapneshNaik I have added some more examples of the Laravel side.

Comment: change your web root to /project-folder/public, and it should work

Comment: It is already that. The site is set up and working. The issue is with the trailing slash redirect loses the virtual path. This is why I think there is an issue in IIS but I can't seem to find it.